# C++11 delegated constructor and typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I try to compile some code in visual studio 2013 (community edition), but I have problems : the following code refuse to compile.

```
struct X
{
    X(double y);
};

typedef X Z;
struct Y : public Z
{
    using Z::Z;            
};
```

The problem is the line using Z::Z.  It gives me an error C2039: 'Z' : is not a member of 'X'

Is this code valid ? or is this a bug ?

Answer (score 5):

The feature you're using is *inheriting constructors,* not *delegating constructors.* And as per [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx), inheriting constructors is not supported by VS 2013 RTM.

VS 2013 *does* support delegating constructors, but that's a different feature—one constructor delegating the member initialisation to another. This would be an example:

```
struct X
{
  int i;

  X(int i) : i(i) {}

  X() : X(42) {}  // delegating constructor
};
```

---

If you *need* to inherit constructors in a compiler which doesn't support that, you can create a workaround by defining a perfectly forwarding constructor taking anything. It's no 100% the same effect, but it should be good enough for most uses:

```
struct Y : X
{
  template <class... Arg>
  Y(Arg &&... arg) : X(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...) {}
};
```

It will not have the same `noexcept` characteristic as the base class constructor(s), but then again, VS 2013 doesn't support `noexcept`.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, now I know precisely the difference between inheriting and delegating constructor. I am using VS 2013 community edition which is quite recent and it seems to support inherting constructors at least partially since it works if Y derives from X class and inherits from X constructors ....